# How to loop through sql results and display results in JLabel

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I'm trying to display sql results into JLabel. In the database there is a table called courses. In that table there are 4 columns (id,name,img_path,description) I'm currently trying to display only the course name. When I print out the results to the command line it worked. But when I'm trying to display the results in a JLabel. Nothing happens.

Here's the db.java file, used to connect to the database

```
package my.welcomescreen;
import java.sql.*;

public class db {

public static Connection dbconnect(){
    Connection con=null;
    try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/st2", "root", "");


}
catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
   return con; 
}

}
```

Here's the Welcome_screen.java file which contains the main method

```
package my.welcomescreen;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Welcome_screen extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public Welcome_screen() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    signin_btn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    signup_btn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    cname = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 102));

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 102));
    jPanel1.addInputMethodListener(new java.awt.event.InputMethodListener() {
        public void caretPositionChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
        }
        public void inputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
            jPanel1InputMethodTextChanged(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 58)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jLabel1.setText("WELCOME");

    signin_btn.setText("Sign in");
    signin_btn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            signin_btnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    signup_btn.setText("Sign up");
    signup_btn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            signup_btnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 1, 58)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jLabel2.setText("to");

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 58)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jLabel3.setText("E-Tutes !");

    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jLabel4.setText("E-tutes is a great place for learn new programming languages.");

    jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jLabel5.setText(" You can find learn all the popular programming languges and frameworks in one place !");

    jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jLabel6.setText("It's totally free ! You can follow any of our courses for free with no hidden costs !");

    jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel7.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jLabel7.setText("Don't miss this opportunity ! ");

    jLabel8.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 255));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 403, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(157, 157, 157))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addGap(90, 90, 90))))
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 564, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addGap(197, 197, 197))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(184, 184, 184)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 122, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(cname)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(signin_btn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 113, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(signup_btn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 113, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
            .addContainerGap(69, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel4)
            .addGap(1, 1, 1)
            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(1, 1, 1)
            .addComponent(jLabel6)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel7)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                    .addComponent(cname)
                    .addGap(170, 170, 170))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(150, 150, 150)))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(signin_btn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(signup_btn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        


private void signin_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    new Sign_in().setVisible(true);
}                                          

private void signup_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    new Sign_up().setVisible(true);
}                                          

private void jPanel1InputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {                                               

}                                              

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Welcome_screen courses = new Welcome_screen();
    courses.getCourses();


    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Welcome_screen().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}

public void getCourses(){
    db obj = new db();
    obj.dbconnect();
    String Query = "select * from courses";
    try{
        Connection con = obj.dbconnect();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(Query);

        while(rs.next()){
            String value = rs.getString("name");
            jLabel8.setText(value); //this is the part that I set sql result to the JLabel       
}

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }


}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel cname;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JButton signin_btn;
private javax.swing.JButton signup_btn;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: If your query works (not sure it does), you are re-setting the label text for each row in `courses`, meaning that if the last name in the result set happens to be empty, the label will be blank. Are you sure the label is visible in the UI? Also, you have an extra call to `dbconnect()` at the beginning of the method for no apparent reason.

Comment: You don't need the `while` loop if you want to set one value from database to the `jLabel8`, otherwise, it'll overwrite it with every loop

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Logically *"How to loop through sql results and display results in JLabel"* Would require 1 label, not 8. Trim the rest of the cruft as well (e.g. setting colors) that has nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but a `JTable` or `JList` would be better suited to displaying lists of elements